Memory problems with "strtok" implementation. (c)
I need to make a function that splits a string with a delimiter.
I know it's a lot more convoluted than it needs to be but that's what i came up with:
#include "libft.h"

static int  ft_countstrings(char const *s, char c)
{
    int i;
    int count;

    i = 0;
    count = 0;
    if (!*s || !c)
        return (0);
    while (s[i])
    {
        while (s[i] == c)
            i++;
        if (s[i])
            count++;
        while (s[i] != c && s[i])
            i++;
    }
    return (count);
}

static int  ft_findend(char const *s, char c, int i)
{
    while (s[i] && s[i] != c)
        i++;
    return (i);
}

static char *ft_substring(char const *s, int start, int end)
{
    int     i;
    char    *substr;

    i = 0;
    if (end < start || start < 0 || end < 0)
        return (NULL);
    substr = malloc(sizeof(char) * (end - start + 1));
    if (substr == NULL)
        return (NULL);
    while (start < end)
        substr[i++] = s[start++];
    substr[i] = '\0';
    return (substr);
}

char    **ft_split(char const *s, char c)
{
    int     i;
    int     j;
    int     count;
    char    **array;

    count = ft_countstrings(s, c);
    array = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * (count + 1));
    if (!array || !s)
        return (0);
    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    while (s[i] && j < count)
    {
        while (s[i] == c)
            i++;
        if (s[i])
        {
            array[j] = ft_substring(s, i, ft_findend(s, c, i));
            i = ft_findend(s, c, i) + 1;
            j++;
        }
    }
    array[j] = NULL;
    return (array);
}

It seems to me like it is working just fine but when i run a program that tests it, it passes all test cases but one and I get this error message that makes absolutely no sense to me.
ft_split        : 1.KO Abort

Errors found:
For ft_split, in /Users/clement/francinette/tests/libft/fsoares/test_split.c:

Error in test 1: ft_split("hello!", 32:' '): Memory problems!
     in sigabort utils.c:58:1
     in ft_split ft_split.c:73:9
     in test_single_split test_split.c:59:9
     in test_split test_split.c:79:6
     in main test_split.c:101:2
14  dyld                                0x00007ff803a5e386 start + 1942

=================================================================
==76889==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: global-buffer-overflow on address 0x000104e26de7 at pc 0x000104e25eac bp 0x7ff7bb0e3560 sp 0x7ff7bb0e3558
READ of size 1 at 0x000104e26de7 thread T0
    #0 0x104e25eab in ft_split ft_split.c:73
    #1 0x104e201b5 in test_single_split test_split.c:59
    #2 0x104e203ac in test_split test_split.c:79
    #3 0x104e20666 in main test_split.c:101
    #4 0x7ff803a5e385 in start+0x795 (dyld:x86_64+0xfffffffffff5c385)

0x000104e26de7 is located 57 bytes before global variable '.str.9' defined in 'test_split.c' (0x104e26e20) of size 15
  '.str.9' is ascii string 'hello!zzzzzzzz'
0x000104e26de7 is located 25 bytes before global variable '.str.8' defined in 'test_split.c' (0x104e26e00) of size 15
  '.str.8' is ascii string 'xxxxxxxxhello!'
0x000104e26de7 is located 0 bytes after global variable '.str.7' defined in 'test_split.c' (0x104e26de0) of size 7
  '.str.7' is ascii string 'hello!'
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: global-buffer-overflow ft_split.c:73 in ft_split


Reverse the condition for the while loop inside ft_split. while (j < count && s[i]) The problem is that i is out of range.
